# ServerSelectionTimeoutError: documentdb.documents.azure.com:10255: timed out

Tags: python-3.x, azure, port, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am running a mongodb application to connect to azure cosmosdb running locally. I am running an already built flask app. Which port on my machine do I need to enable, to connect to the remote cosmosdb?

```
Anaconda environment: Python 3.6
MongoClient
replicaset is globaldb
ssl is True
```

My flask app gives the above error

Answer (score 1):

Check this thread out: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/256. Start by using /EnableMongoDbEndpoint flag and point it to 10250 port. It might work.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. I will test this emulator as well tomorrow. 

Comment: Since I am using Azure cosmos db service how do I put the URI with `/EnableMongoDbEndpoint`flag in it? My current URI is `mongodb://dmpmldocumentdb:<primary_password>==@dmpmldocumentdb.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb